# SSLSocket getOutputStream() blocks after handshake

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, encryption

I am opening an SSLSocket on the client side to connect to the server.
But trying to get the `socket.getOutputStream()` blocks the code, without outputting any errors.
I am flushing both streams, but it still doesn't work.

Server:

```
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
        socket.setUseClientMode(false);
        try{
        socket.setSoTimeout(0);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(handshakeCompletedEvent -> {
            try{
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                writer.println("Setup"); writer.flush();

                while(running){
                    if(!socket.isConnected() || socket.isClosed()){
                        disconnect();
                        return;
                    }
                    for(Iterator<String> pendingIterator = pendingMessages.iterator(); pendingIterator.hasNext();){
                        String message = pendingIterator.next();
                        pendingIterator.remove();
                        writer.println(message); writer.flush();
                    }

                    //Auto decrypt when message arrives, but no thread blocking
                    if(reader.ready()){
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        socket.startHandshake();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        disconnect();
    }
```

Client:

```
            socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener(){
            @Override
            public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent handshakeCompletedEvent){
                try{
                    Log.i("Update", "Did handshake");

                    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    writer.flush();
                    Log.i("Update", "Writer");
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    Log.i("Update", "Reader");

                    while(isRunning){
                        try{
                            writer.println("Test");
                            writer.flush();
                            Log.i("DATA", "DATA SENT");
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                    socket.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        socket.startHandshake();
```

Comment: Why do all that `startHandshake()` / `addHandshakeCompletedListener()` stuff? The *initial* handshake happens automatically, and is synchronous. Get rid of that handshake code and just begin using the `reader` and `writer`. --- My *guess* is that you're deadlocking yourself. The `getInputStream()` call will not return until initial synchronous handshake is complete, but the initial handshake is not completing because the `HandshakeCompletedListener` is called as the final step, and it never returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the handshake completed listener. Its purpose is to let to check he peer certificate, negotiated cipher suite, etc. Not to carry out the transaction. Remove it all and put it inline. You don't need even to call `startHandshake()`. It will happen automatically on the first I/O.